# Runtime exec on ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I try to run the wavemon command from java and read the output.
But I can't make the Runtime.exec method work.

The echo command in comments works and prints "hello", but the wavemon command just returns "". Wavemon is installed, I even tried it with it's full path (/usr/bin/wavemon) as an argument.
Nothing works.

```
// call wavemon
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] cmd = { "sh", "-c", "wavemon", "-i wlan1", "-d" };
//String[] cmd = { "sh", "-c","echo hello" };
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
proc.waitFor();

// read wavemon output into string
Scanner is =  new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (is.hasNext()) {
    buffer.append(is.nextLine());

}

proc.destroy();
System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

The output of the wavemon command starts with an empty line, but since I use a scanner, this should not matter?

```
$ wavemon -i wlan1 -d

Configured device: wlan1 (IEEE 802.11abgn)
Security: WPA, WPA2, TKIP, CCMP
...
```

A little detail, this code is used in the Spring framework (spring-boot, tomcat container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need the "sh -c". Try just using only:

```
String[] cmd = { "wavemon", "-i","wlan1", "-d" };
```

Also, you should put the `waitFor()` after reading the lines from the scanner, as this holds the thread until the process is done. However, the process might not finish until you read it's output. You can get even fancier and read all of the streams on separate threads.

This article has all the details on it http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: I tried it, and I already read this article, but I still don't see what I'm doing wrong :s

Comment: Possibly the output gets written to stderror and you need to read that stream?

Comment: Also try without the "sh -c" part. I never needed that before, even though I am executing programs like this on ubuntu. And if you use "sh -c" try it like this: { "sh", "-c", "wavemon -i wlan1 -d" }. Per the man page "sh -c" reads from the following string. So I am assuming it expects it in one piece.

Comment: Not working yet (still trying things) but apparently there was an error on the sterr: input is not from a terminal (wavemon uses the isatty command to check this). Is this a problem for running with runtime.exec? or just wrong arguments in my call?

Comment: Yes, that would be the problem. Javas runtime.exec does not actually act as if it is a command line it is simply a command to execute a program.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the solution, it is working, and it is the easy way, don't know what I missed but it's ok now: String[] cmd = { "wavemon", "-i","wlan1", "-d" }; Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help, I edited my post so the solution is not stuck in the comments